# Ordering XML in LINQ by potentially missing child nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'am working on an XML file of the following structure:

```
<vco:ItemDetail>
    <cac:Item>
      ...
      <cac:RecommendedRetailPrice>
        <cbc:PriceAmount amountCurrencyID="EUR">4.95</cbc:PriceAmount>
        <cbc:BaseQuantity quantityUnitCode="EA">1</cbc:BaseQuantity>
      </cac:RecommendedRetailPrice>
      ...
    </cac:Item>
    ...
</vco:ItemDetail>
```

The `RecommendedRetailPrice` and/or `PriceAmount` may not exists for every `Item`.
Nevertheless I'd like to sort all `Items` by their respective `RecommendedRetailPrices`.
So I ended up with the following code which works fine, but has to check for nulls at every stage in some ghastly nested if statements:

```
//full_xml is of type XDocument
var most_expensive = full_xml
    .Element("ItemDetails")
    .Elements(vco + "ItemDetail")
    .Elements(cac + "Item")
    .OrderBy(el => 
        {
            var rrp = el.Element(cac + "RecommendedRetailPrice");
            string val = null;
            if(rrp != null) {
                var pa = rrp.Element(cbc + "PriceAmount");
                if(pa != null) {
                    val = rrp.Value;
                }
            }
            if (val != null) {
                return Convert.ToDouble(val);
            }
            else {
                return 0.0;
            }
        }                 
    )
    .Last();
```

This might not be so bad in this case, but I imagine there has to be a more idiomatic way to do this. Consider sorting something by an optional child node that is 8 levels down.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If zero or one elements can exists, then I would use `Elements()` rather than `Element()` then select the `FirstOrDefault`. Then use the [explicit cast operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986933.aspx) of `XElement` to get your value.

Something like this

```
var most_expensive = full_xml
  .Element("ItemDetails")
  .Elements(vco + "ItemDetail")
  .Elements(cac + "Item")
  .OrderBy(el =>        
        el.Elements(cac + "RecommendedRetailPrice")
          .Select(rrp => (double?) rrp.Elements(cbc + "PriceAmount"))
          .FirstOrDefault() ?? 0.0
   ).Last();
```

Comment: This errored out for me with:
The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @user2473741 My bad, try the above.

Comment: Had to change rrp.Elements to rrp.Element. Works fine now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Create a method to do your operation (I know I know we all want to make pretty Lambda expressions and not make new methods)

```
private static double GetPrice(XElement retail, string priceElement)
{
    // short circuting will stop as soon as the statement is false
    if (retail != null && retail.Element(priceElement) != null)
    {
        return Convert.ToDouble(retail.Element(priceElement).Value);
    }

    return 0.0;
}
```

Your linq now looks like this awesomeness...

```
var most_expensive = full_xml
                    .Element("ItemDetails")
                    .Elements(vco + "ItemDetail")
                    .Elements(cac + "Item")
                    .OrderBy(el => GetPrice(el.Element(cac + "RecommendedRetailPrice"), cbc + "PriceAmount"))
                    .Last();
```

I'm sure the method could be re-used in other places where you're going to have to get the price as well so it will be a useful piece of code later on.

If you want you can also use the Ternary operator to make the method shorter

```
private static double GetPrice(XElement retail, string priceElement)
{
    return (retail != null && retail.Element(priceElement) != null) ?
            Convert.ToDouble(retail.Element(priceElement).Value) : 0.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sans the namespaces:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"
    <ItemDetails>
        <ItemDetail>
            <Item>
                <RecommendedRetailPrice>
                    <PriceAmount>4.95</PriceAmount>
                </RecommendedRetailPrice>
            </Item>
        </ItemDetail>
    </ItemDetails>
");

var result = doc
    .Element("ItemDetails")
    .Elements("ItemDetail")
    .Elements("Item")
    .OrderBy(item =>
        item.Elements("RecommendedRetailPrice")
            .Elements("PriceAmount")
            .Select(pa => Convert.ToDouble(pa.Value,
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            .FirstOrDefault())
    .Last();

Console.WriteLine(result);
```